# Authenticating with AndroidX biometric latest version causes crash [Android]

Tags: android, android-biometric-prompt

When using the androidx biometric library's latest version I got following error which caused the app to crash

App crashed when calling `BiometricPrompt`'s `authenticate` method.

**androidx.biometric:biometric:1.0.0-beta01**

Running on device and emulator with android 28 and 29.

The log

```
09-04 14:54:44.717  9394  9394 E AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
09-04 14:54:44.717  9394  9394 E AndroidRuntime: java.lang.BootstrapMethodError: Exception from call site #3 bootstrap method
09-04 14:54:44.717  9394  9394 E AndroidRuntime:     at androidx.biometric.BiometricFragment.<init>(BiometricFragment.java:86)
09-04 14:54:44.717  9394  9394 E AndroidRuntime:     at androidx.biometric.BiometricFragment.newInstance(BiometricFragment.java:187)
09-04 14:54:44.717  9394  9394 E AndroidRuntime:     at androidx.biometric.BiometricPrompt.authenticateInternal(BiometricPrompt.java:681)
09-04 14:54:44.717  9394  9394 E AndroidRuntime:     at androidx.biometric.BiometricPrompt.authenticate(BiometricPrompt.java:658)
```

Does anybody know what's causing it? Any workaround?

Comment: Sounds like you should [file a bug against Biometric](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=559537).

Comment: @ianhanniballake bug filed!
https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/140508526

Answer (score 0):

This issue is resolved in beta02, which is releasing ~September19.

It's due to your app likely using Java7 which doesn't support lambdas, which the library was internally using. We've removed them and changed the library to build with Java7.

Curious, were you integrated with previous versions of the library? I'm surprised this didn't crash before.